React: POST /refresh not setting refresh_token cookie
I am setting up login and refresh logic for my react app and running into a refresh token issue. I know that the overall refresh logic is sound because on postman it is working just fine. It's within my application where the problem is.
I have my main server.js on PORT 8080 and authServer.js on PORT 8081. My front end application is using VITE and on http://localhost:5173.
My issue is req.cookies is always an empty object {} and it fails with status 401.
As I said, on postman everything works great. But after logging into my application and refreshing the page, /refresh has the following response:
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 401
statusText: "Unauthorized"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:8081/refresh

Here is the code:
authServer.js
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import "dotenv/config";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import { api } from "./db/queries.js";

const app = express();
const PORT = 8081;
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:5173",
  credentials: true,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

// Define routes after middleware

const generateTokens = (user) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  const accessToken = jwt.sign(user, process.env.VITE_ACCESS_TOKEN, {
    expiresIn: "15s",
  });
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  const refreshToken = jwt.sign(user, process.env.VITE_REFRESH_TOKEN, {
    expiresIn: "1d",
  });
  return { accessToken, refreshToken };
};

app.post("/refresh", (req, res) => {
  const token = req.cookies.refresh_token;
  if (token == null) return res.sendStatus(401);
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.VITE_REFRESH_TOKEN, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
    const { accessToken, refreshToken } = generateTokens({ name: user.name });
    res.cookie("refresh_token", refreshToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "None",
    });
    res.json({ accessToken: accessToken });
  });
});

AuthContext.jsx
import { useContext, createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const AuthContext = createContext();

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const refreshToken = async () => {
    const url = "http://localhost:8081/refresh";
    console.log("Attempting to refresh token...");

    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });

      console.log("Received response from /refresh:", response);

      if (!response.ok) {
        console.error(
          `Failed to refresh token. Status code: ${response.status}`
        );
        setStatus(401);
        return;
      }

      const token = await response.json();
      console.log("Received token data:", token);

      const { accessToken } = token;
      console.log("Access token:", accessToken);

      setIsAuthenticated(!!accessToken);
      console.log("Authentication status set to:", !!accessToken);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error occurred during token refresh:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        isAuthenticated,
        refreshToken,
        status,
        setStatus,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthProvider;

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};

ProtectedRoutes.jsx
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "../context/AuthContext";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const ProtectedRoutes = ({ children }) => {
  const { isAuthenticated, refreshToken } = useAuth();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const refresh = async () => {
      try {
        await refreshToken();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during token refresh:", error);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      refresh();
    } else {
      setIsLoading(false); 
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated, refreshToken]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>; 
  }

  // Once loading is done, check authentication status
  return isAuthenticated ? children : <Navigate to="/login" />;
};

EDIT:
The solution was to add credentials: "include" to /users/login

You see the refresh_token in the Developer Tools and in the request header, but it's not received on the backend. Is that correct?

I do not see it in dev tools. I only see the correct headers in postman. I don't see any headers in dev tools and see this in back end: Cookies:  [Object: null prototype] {}
Headers:  undefined

Then where is the code that should set the group of tokens in the browser?

Remove or comment out this part: if (token == null) return res.sendStatus(401);. In the first call, logically, it should be undefined or null. I guess this is what stops the rest of the logic.

the tokens are initially set in browser during /login:  res.cookie("refresh_token", refreshToken, {
httpOnly: true,
sameSite: "None",
});

removing the token ==null line doesn't fix the issue. The issue is really I'm not sure why the cookie/refresh_token isn't being set in the POST /refresh.

Also verify. What are you trying to check when there is no token? In a real scenario, you should first sign in from the frontend, then the backend should send you the access and refresh tokens. Only after that can you check or verify anything. But first things first—the backend should send or set the access and refresh tokens as a response to the login process without any kind of verification.


By default, a cross-origin CORS request is made without
credentials. So, no cookies, no client certs, no automatic
Authorization header, and Set-Cookie on the response is ignored.
However, same-origin requests include credentials.

Since the login request is a cross-origin CORS request and it did NOT have credentials explicitly set, though the server did it part by setting the header Set-Cookie, the client had ignored it. This was the reason for the failure. And the solution as you found, to include credentials.
This post - How to win at CORS, talks about this in detail.
