res.cookie from express is not setting the cookie in the client
I'm facing a problem with my express route, where the cookie that is sent as a response is not set on the client, the strange thing is that the cookie is sent in the header, but it doesn't appear in the browser.
Here is the middlewares
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("tiny"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false, limit: "100kb" }));
app.use(cookieParser());

Here is my route
export const createUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        const { name, password, username, email } = req.body;

        // Create a value to append before the password
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(15);

        // Create a hash password
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

        const user = await db.user.create({
            data: {
                name,
                password,
                username: hashedPassword,
                email,
            },
        });

        const session = await lucia.createSession(user.id, {});

        const sessionCookie = lucia.createSessionCookie(session.id);

        res
            .status(StatusCodes.ACCEPTED)
            .cookie(sessionCookie.name, sessionCookie.value)
            .json({ sucess: true });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res
            .status(StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .json({ sucess: false, error });
    }
};


Here's the header
As you can see, doesn't appear in the client
I'm trying to define a cookie in the server and send to the client

Hi, The answer in this post may help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78858918/react-post-refresh-not-setting-refresh-token-cookie/78860425#78860425

Have you tried definying the path, httpOnly and sameSite properties of the cookie when sending to the client?

Is this just a suggestion rather than a definite answer?

Don't know 100% the answer, but I've experienced the same issue and It was resolved with that

I was going to suggest it might be better as a comment, if you were suggesting possibilities. But perhaps it's just how you phrased the answer.
